# Thymleaf escape character

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I want to put JavaScript onclick attribute using Thymleaf.

I wrote the code like this

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" data-toggle="tooltip"
  th:attr="onclick=|showCartItemRemoveModal('${purchase.lineItemId}' , '${purchase.productName}')|"
  title="Delete from cart">
```

this code is working. I am facing problem when productName contains special characters like this

```
productName = "Test Product's"
```

then JavaScript function looks like this

```
onclick="showCartItemRemoveModal('184a4c6h776' , '"Test Product's"')"
```

I need to escape double and single quote charecter from product name. How can I do this?

Comment: JavaScript is not Java

Answer (score 1):

There is an another way of doing this

Instead of passing product name as parameter in javascript function ..you can add a data variable as a custom attribute in button tag and get value of custom attribute using jquery or javascript.
code will looks like as below..

HTML Code:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" data-toggle="tooltip"
th:id="${purchase.lineItemId}" th:data-productname="${purchase.productName}"
th:attr="onclick=|showCartItemRemoveModal('${purchase.lineItemId}')|"
title="Delete from cart">
```

Javascript function code

```
function showCartItemRemoveModal(lineItemId) {
   var productName = $("#lineItemId").attr("data-productname");
   console.log("product Name is: "+productName );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know thymeleaf, but I strongly suggest something like

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" data-toggle="tooltip"
data-itemid="${purchase.lineItemId}" data-productname="${purchase.productName}"
title="Delete from cart">
```

and then delegate from the nearest static container I call someContainer here

```
 document.getElementById("someContainer").addEventListener("click",e => {
   const tgt = e.target;
   if (e.dataset.itemid) {
     showCartItemRemoveModal(e.target)
   }
 })
```

and in the showCartItemRemoveModal you can do

```
const showCartItemRemoveModal = tgt => {
  console.log(tgt.dataset.itemid,tgt.dataset.productname)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question about escaping text:

If you want your JavaScript function to contain the following text, where the single quote is correctly escaped...

```
onclick="showCartItemRemoveModal('184a4c6h776' , 'Test Product\'s')"
```

...then you need to provide that `\` character in your Java string. To include a `\` in a Java string like this, you need to use two backslashes, because a single backslash already has a special meaning in Java, for specific character escape sequences *.

The same applies to double-quotes inside your strings, also.

In these cases, the `\\` in Java will result in a single `\` in JavaScript - which is what you want. You have *escaped the Java escape* character - turning it into a regular `\`.

In Java this would therefore be:

```
String s = "Test Product\\'s";
```

**Having said that, the approach recommended by mplungian in their answer is the right approach, in my opinion.**

---

* See the "Escape sequences" section in [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html). It just so happens that your `\'` is one of Java's valid escape sequences - so it does not actually mean a literal backslash followed by a literal single quote.